# Bad practice to use composer 'scripts' feature?

Tags: php, scripting, composer-php

I have some scripts that need shell features (e.g. loops) so my project has a bin directory with shell scripts in it.  But I also have lots of one-liners in composer.json as scripts.

This means the poor sap that comes after me has to remember whether to run:

`$ composer some-script`

or just

`$ some-script`

I don't like that.   That leads me to wonder if I should just rip all the one-liners out of composer.json and make shell scripts for them so that they're in one place.  What's best practice here?